# Perl - opening xlsx file error

Tags: perl

I am trying to open xlsx file. But, when I parse that file like the code below, I get the below error:

```
Can't locate object method "new" via package "SpreadSheet::XLSX" (perhaps you forgot to load "SpreadSheet::XLSX"?)
```

Do you have a work around for this which can help me to parse the xlsx file? Also, I have the file present in the path provided.

Code written is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::Iconv;
use Spreadsheet::XLSX;
use Date::Format;

my $converter = Text::Iconv->new( "utf-8", "windows-1251" );

# Read the data from a file.
my $prod_otp = SpreadSheet::XLSX->new( '/home/okal/Book1.xlsx', $converter );

if ( !defined $prod_otp ) {
    die $prod_otp->error(), ".\n";
}

for my $worksheet ( $prod_otp->worksheet() ) {
    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
    my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();

    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) {
        for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {
            my $cell = worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
            next unless $cell;

            print "Row, Col = ($row, $col)\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: hi miller, just wanted to check with you why is this question on hold? I was able to pass this error as suggested by RET. how can i close the discussion  as my question is resolved?

Answer (score 5):

It's either `SpreadSheet:XLSX` or `Spreadsheet::XLSX`. Perl Module names are Case Sensitive.

The fact it blows up at the call to `->new()` suggests the `use` statement is probably the correct variant.

Comment: Yep; big S, then little s.  [Spreadsheet::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::XLSX)

Comment: Thanks Ret Jim. I was able to pass that error. Thanks for your input.